# Send a text to Slack Webhook containing selected user

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks, slack, slack-api, urlfetch

I am trying to send a message from Google Apps Script to Slack via a Webhook URL that works great, but I can't figure out how to send a highlighted or selected  user in that text. For example '@UsernameTest how are you?' is something I want to send to a person or channel, but it doesn't work. I figured out that to highlight the channel i.e. send '@Channel' I just needed to write , but that is not what I want. I tried <@UserID> but it still didn't work. (I Received the UserID by using inspector tool on the web-version of Slack on the user.)

The [Slack API docs](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#variables) helped some but still have problems.

Here is the code I'm using, thank you.

```
var SLACK_URL = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...

function sendSlackMessage(text) {
  var slackMessage = {
    text: "@UsernameTest how are you? and all you guys <@Channel>?" 
  };

  var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(slackMessage)
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(SLACK_URL, options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for sending user mentions is `<@[user-id]>`
And for channel pings the syntax is `<!channel>` or `<!here>`.

e.g. to send a mention to a user with user ID `U1234567` you need to sent the string:

`<@U12345678> how are you? and all you guys <!channel>?"`

For more information on how to link users and channel see [the documentation](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users).

Note that `@username` is being phased out and should no longer be used. For more details see ["A lingering farewell to the username"](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2017-09-the-one-about-usernames) from Slack.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have 3 `"` in that line:

```
text: "@UsernameTest how are you? and all you guys "<@Channel>?"
```